# How can I add Context Menu Items to C# Editor of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-sdk

I found some example where we can add context menu items to C# code editor at compile time but not at runtime. How can we do this at run-time.

Comment: could you explain in more detailed about run-time/compile-time?

Comment: after my plugin Loaded into Memory , then on some bases I have to decide how many and Context menu items I have to add..

Answer (score 2):

Buttons belonging to commands are always added to commandbars (menus, toolbars, context menus) when the extension is registered within Visual Studio (a one-time event).

What can be customized is whether the command is enabled/disabled and whether buttons created from it are visible/invisible. This can be customized:

1) When the extension is not loaded yet, it is done in the .vsct file through command flags such as [DefaultDisabled, DefaultInvisible, etc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491716.aspx) or [VisibilityConstraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166512.aspx).

2) When the extension is loaded, it is done using the [DynamicVisibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166512.aspx) command flag in .vsct file and [OleMenuCommand.BeforeQueryStatus Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.olemenucommand.beforequerystatus.aspx). See for example: [Dynamic Menu Commands in Visual Studio Packages – Part 2](http://www.codingodyssey.com/2008/03/22/dynamic-menu-commands-in-visual-studio-packages-part-2/)